# How to check which menu file is inflated in BottomNavigationView?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I use 2 different menu for my bottom navigation view called

1. bottom_navigation_menu.xml
2. bottom_navigation_menu_verified.xml

I need to set different action based on what is the current menu inflated in my bottom navigation view. I want to make something like this

```
lateinit var bottomNavigationView : BottomNavigationView

if (bottomNavigationView.menu == R.menu.bottom_navigation_menu_verified) {
   // do something here
}
```

but the code above is invalid because `bottomNavigationView.menu` will return `Menu` data type and `R.menu.bottom_navigation_menu_verified` will return `int`, type doesn't match. so how to check what is the current inflated menu in my bottom navigation view ?

java/kotlin is okay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably check for a specific `MenuItem`:

```
if (null != bottomNavigationView.menu.findItem(R.id.bottom_navigation_menu_item1)) {
   // do something here
}
```

Comment: Multiple menus may contain the same items, and adding a test item to each menu means you have to either have a debug menu (which means you are not testing the right menu), or include the test items in the release version of the app which is unacceptable.

You would have test all items are present, which is kind of hacky.